# Find closest value within factor levels in R

Tags: r, vector, subset, sapply

I have four vectors, A and B are numeric values and C1 and C2 are factors with the same levels. A and C1 are the same length as are B and C2:

```
set.seed(47) ## for reproducibility
A = rnorm(100)
C1 = rep(c('vv','xx','yy','zz'),times=25)

B = rnorm(40)
C2 = rep(c('vv','xx','yy','zz'),times=10)
```

I would like to create a new vector A2 which is the closest value of B to each element of A within the same level of C1 and C2. This code achieves the closest value to each element of A from the entire vector B:

```
A2 = B[sapply(A, function(x) which.min(abs(B - x)))]
```

But I can't figure out how to make A2 consist of the closest value of B when C1 = C2?
e.g. if element i of A is 0.2 and element i of C1 is zz, then I would like element i of A2 to be the closest value of `B[which(C2=="zz")]` to 0.2.

Comment: you had the right idea, just do it for each unique level `sapply(unique(C1), function(ii) B[C2 == ii][sapply(A[C1 == ii], function(x) which.min(abs(B[C2 == ii] - x)))])`

Comment: Thanks - this works but produces four columns instead of A2 being a vector of equivalent length to A, which I was hoping for - but it looks like I didn't describe that properly in the question!

Comment: just use `c(x)` or `c(sapply(...))`

Answer (score 2):

I would join and filter:

```
set.seed(47) ## for reproducibility
A = rnorm(100)
C1 = rep(c('vv','xx','yy','zz'),times=25)

B = rnorm(40)
C2 = rep(c('vv','xx','yy','zz'),times=10)


## put data in data frames
df_a = data.frame(A, C1)
df_b = data.frame(B, C2)

library(dplyr)
result = 
  df_a %>% 
  mutate(a_id = 1:n()) %>%
  left_join(df_b, by = c("C1" = "C2")) %>%
  group_by(C1, a_id) %>%
  slice(which.min(abs(B - A))) %>%
  arrange(a_id)

result
# # A tibble: 100 x 4
# # Groups:   C1, a_id [100]
#          A C1     a_id       B
#      <dbl> <chr> <int>   <dbl>
#  1  1.99   vv        1  1.66  
#  2  0.711  xx        2  0.771 
#  3  0.185  yy        3  0.227 
#  4 -0.282  zz        4 -0.474 
#  5  0.109  vv        5  0.0922
#  6 -1.09   xx        6 -1.06  
#  7 -0.985  yy        7 -0.425 
#  8  0.0151 zz        8  0.321 
#  9 -0.252  vv        9 -0.263 
# 10 -1.47   xx       10 -1.06  
# # ... with 90 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response - but I need A2 to be the same length as A, as in the sapply example I gave, or in your example, it would be a new column in df_a ... 
Sorry if the question was not clear! I need a new vector containing the closest value of B for each value of A, when C1 = C2.

Comment: Oops - missed the *each* element of A - will edit in just a second.

Comment: Added an ID row to `df_a` and grouped by that as well - now you'll have the same number of rows as the original A.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a case to exploit *data.table*'s rolling join to find the nearest value. That will avoid the need to materialise a full join of every case to every case, and then reduce the large result to find the correct value.

I'll steal @gregor's `df_a` and `df_b` data from the other answer:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df_a)
setDT(df_b)

df_b[df_a, on=c("C2==C1","B==A"), roll="nearest", .(A, C1, B=x.B)]

#                  A C1           B
#   1:  1.9946963377 vv  1.66073540
#   2:  0.7111425051 xx  0.77115553
#   3:  0.1854052843 yy  0.22685013
#   4: -0.2817650147 zz -0.47422502
#   5:  0.1087755466 vv  0.09222070
#   6: -1.0857374702 xx -1.05550522
#   etc etc
# 100:  0.0039447933 zz  0.32133042
#                  A C1           B
```

Comment: This works on the example I gave, but when I try it on my more complicated real dataset, it produces this error:
"Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin || !anyDuplicated(f__,  : 
  Join results in 885 rows; more than 633 = nrow(x)+nrow(i). Check for duplicate key values in i each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try by=.EACHI to run j for each group to avoid the large allocation. If you are sure you wish to proceed, rerun with allow.cartesian=TRUE. ..."
Any thoughts? The other solutions work without any similar error.

Comment: I'd try the suggestion *If you are sure you wish to proceed, rerun with allow.cartesian=TRUE* as an additional argument - looks like it's just a preventive measure that a large temporary dataset is created which might indicate a join that isn't working as intended. In this case, it's probably expected however.

Comment: If so then the A2 equivalent is much longer than A (885 vs 481 rows). The error disappears if I remove duplicated B and C2 pairs from the df_b equivalent... annoyingly, I can't reproduce this with a simple version with duplicates, e.g. there is no error with: 
A = rep(seq(from=1, to =5, by=1), times=20)
B = rep(seq(from=0.6, to =4.6, by=1), times=8)
df_a = data.frame(A, C1)
df_b = data.frame(B, C2)

Comment: You could also wrap `df_b` in `unique` first, to avoid the large join product - `unique(df_b)[df_a, on=c("C2==C1"...` - I don't think you'll be able to replicate with a small example unless it triggers the `nrow(x)+nrow(i)` size criteria.